# Loading image file stored In LocalState folder by URI

Tags: cordova, winjs

I have a Windows 8 Cordova application where I am trying to load an image by URI.  The application downloads image files to the App's `LocalState` folder.

When I use the absolute path or a `file` scheme name *file://*, I get an invalid operation exception.

For testing purposes I placed a test image in the local state folder called "test.jpg" and tried loading in with the `ms-appx` scheme.  This does not throw an exception, but the image does not load.

I've with the following URIs:

`ms-appx://test.jpg`

`ms-appx://LocalState/test.jpg`

Is it possible to load by URI instead of using a data url? If so, how?

Comment: I never ended up solving this in a timely fashion.  I ended up reading the images from disk and storing in a data-url. I suspect what I want to do above isn't possible due to sandboxing, but I'd like to confirm one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct link to your image is : **'ms-appdata:///local/test.jpg'**

make sure you have 3 '/' after ms-appdata:

Comment: How would you link to an image in the **www** folder when it's called from a plugin, using the Windows Universal platform? Thanks